# Why getting PostForm' object has no attribute 'user?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a small project containing two models User and Post.And a user can have multiple posts.
I have created a custom form `PostForm`.
When ever i am submitting the form it showing me the following error:-

```
'PostForm' object has no attribute 'user'
```

**views.py:-**

```
def add_post(request):
    print("addpost runn")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        print("if part")
        if post_form.is_valid():
            print(post_form)
            post_form.save(commit=False)
            post_form.user = request.user
            post_form.save()
    else:
        print("else part")
        post_form = PostForm()
    return render(request, "addpost.html", {"form": post_form})
```

**forms.py:-**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(label="Write Your Text Here", max_length=200, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3}))
    created_at = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'],
                                     widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

    updated_at = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'],
                                     widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['text']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        post = Post.objects.create_post(
            self.cleaned_data['text'],
            datetime.datetime.now(),
            datetime.datetime.now(),
            self.user,
        )
        return post
```

**manager.py:-**

```
class PostManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_post(self, text, created_at, updated_at, user, **otherfields):
        print(created_at)
        print(updated_at)
        print(text)
        post = self.model(text=text, created_at=created_at, updated_at=updated_at, user=user)
        post.save(using=self._db)
        return post
```

Comment: you did not event make user ForeignKey attribute in `PostForm`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer:

```
instance=post_form.save(commit=False)
instance.user = request.user
instance.save()
```

Comment: Sorry No Change